# Creating a shared library by Eclipse CDT

Tags: c, eclipse, dll, shared-libraries

I am getting this error each time and i do not not what is happening .. can anyone help please ?

@Mike Kinghan this is the new error

```
08:21:40 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project 5exe ****
make all 
Building file: ../5exe.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -I"C:\Users\Dylan Galea\workspace\5\source" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"5exe.d" -MT"5exe.o" -o "5exe.o" "../5exe.c"
../5exe.c: In function 'main':
../5exe.c:42:10: warning: variable 'temp' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  char temp; //temporary storage to remove the extra ( character
      ^
Finished building: ../5exe.c

Building target: 5exe.exe
Invoking: MinGW C Linker
gcc -L"C:\Users\Dylan Galea\workspace\5\Debug -o "5exe.exe"  ./5exe.o   -l5
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
makefile:29: recipe for target '5exe.exe' failed
make: *** [5exe.exe] Error 258

08:21:40 Build Finished (took 463ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your source code (*which you didn't post*) has an unterminated string literal, something like

```
printf("example text %d with an integer , 4);
/*                                     ^ missing `"' /*
```

Comment: There seems to be an error with the subdir.mk because the soruce code has no errors however this file has a red cross on it @iharob

Comment: I think eclipse is telling about this, please post the file then.

Comment: How do i post the file please because I'm new to this?

Answer (score 0):

The backslash ('\') is an escape-character for the shell (`/usr/bin/sh`). So in this line:

```
gcc -I"C:\Users\Dylan Galea\workspace\5\source\" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-    length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"5exe.d" -MT"5exe.o" -o "5exe.o" "../5exe.c"
```

the backslash '\' that follows `source` escapes the following `"`, and the string
`"C:\Users\Dylan Galea\workspace\5\source\"` is parsed as having unbalanced quotes.

Do one of the following:

Escape the backslashes:-

```
-I"C:\\Users\\Dylan Galea\\workspace\\5\\source\\"
```

Replace them with forward slashes:

```
-I"C:/Users/Dylan Galea/workspace/5/source/"
```

Comment: I removed the extra \ that was causing the " to be escaped and it worked but not it's giving me another error ..

Comment: @DylanGalea The new "error" is (as you can see) merely a compiler warning that your program contains an unused local variable. Ignore the warning or remove the variable. This has nothing whatever to do with the problem originally posted, which you say my answer has solved. You cannot recycle one SO question to pose an open-ended
series of problems. For a new problem, ask a new question. Please see [how to accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) on SO.